# How to run custom Gradle task before all others

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My project has a dependency on another library which has a Git repo. I created a task which clones this Git repo into my project. I would like to make all other tasks depend on or run after this task, because the project depends on this library, and, for example, when I do the run task it throws an error, saying:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':run'.
    > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
        > Could not resolve project ...
```

This is fixed if I manually run the task that downloads the library and then the run task, but I want to do the run task and have it automatically run the other task, and then the run task.

I tried writing this in the build file:

```
tasks.matching { it.name != "myTask" }.all {
    this.setDependsOn(listOf("myTask"))
    this.mustRunAfter("myTask")
}
```

but it did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: *but it did not work* What about it did not work? Please update your question to include more information. Was there an error? What was in the console log? What tasks were run? Have you tried any other [examples in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) to add task dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need all the gradle tasks (loop) to depend on your custom `myTask` ; link it to the earliest - ex: `classes` task (if you are a java project) ... `classes.dependsOn myTask` so before your own code compiles - your `myTask` is executed.